# Changing Voice Pitch using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have an app that repeats back what you say, however, rather than just repeat your own voice, I was hoping I could get it to pitch it lower or higher, is this possible?

Method is here;

```
-(void)playOnMainThread:(id)param
{
    if (!outUrl) {
        return;
    }
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"AVAudioPlayer error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    player.delegate = self;
    [player setVolume:10.0];
    [player play];
}
```

Comment: You can use `AVAudioPlayerNode` for that with the help of `AVAudioUnitTimePitch` you can change the pitch easily

Comment: This sounds interesting, how would I implement this (obj-c) ?

Answer (score 2):

So this is how it will be done. You will be needing a couple of things to start off

First import `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Then in .h file

```
AVAudioEngine *audioEngine;
AVAudioPlayerNode *playerNode;
AVAudioFile *avAudioFile;
AVAudioUnitTimePitch *pitch;
AVAudioMixerNode *mixer;
```

You will be needing these things.

Then in .m file

```
-(void)allocInitRecorders
{
    audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    pitch = [[AVAudioUnitTimePitch alloc] init];
    mixer = [[AVAudioMixerNode alloc] init];

    [audioEngine stop];
    [playerNode stop];
    [audioEngine reset];

}


-(void)emptytheRecorders
{
    audioEngine = nil;
    playerNode = nil;

}


-(void)attachingNodes
{

[audioEngine attachNode:playerNode];

[audioEngine attachNode:pitch];
mixer = [audioEngine mainMixerNode];
[audioEngine connect:playerNode to:pitch format:[avAudioFile processingFormat]];
[audioEngine connect:pitch to:mixer format:[avAudioFile processingFormat]];

}


-(NSString *)filePathOfCollaboratedAudio
{


NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Recording"
                                                     ofType:@"m4a"];

return filePath;
}

-(void)playAudio
{

NSError *err = nil;



[self emptytheRecorders];
[self allocInitRecorders];
[self attachingNodes];




BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self filePathOfCollaboratedAudio]];



if (fileExists)
{
    avAudioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:[NSURL URLWithString:[self filePathOfCollaboratedAudio]] error:&err];
}


pitch.pitch = 1000;

[audioEngine prepare];
[audioEngine startAndReturnError:&err];

NSError *error;

AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:avAudioFile.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)avAudioFile.length];

[avAudioFile readIntoBuffer:buffer error:&error];



[playerNode scheduleBuffer:buffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferInterruptsAtLoop completionHandler:^{


}];


if (err != nil) {
    NSLog(@"An error occured");
}
else
{

    [playerNode play];


}
}
```

Then just call the method

```
[self playAudio];
```

and its done

Comment: Hi Rahul, when I try this, I get no sound, and the animation of the voice talking keeps going (mouth keeps moving with no sound). My filepath is not an m4a and is `NSString` would that make a difference?

Comment: where are you storing your audio? In NSBundle and the m4a doesnt make much of a difference. Can i see your code?

Comment: Are we able to go to chat

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that using AVAudioPlayer. You'll need to use a lower level framework like audio units. What you describe (changing the pitch without speeding up the audio) is actually quite complex mathematically.